# Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed

Tags: postgresql

I am not very good with DB so please bear with me.

I am trying to put a very long JSON data to a table, this table was created by Django framework.

I am using Postgres on Heroku. So, when I try to put the data I get the following error:

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.OperationalError: index row size 3496 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "editor_contentmodel_content_2192f49c_uniq"
HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.
```

My DB and table looks something like this:

```
gollahalli-me-django-test::DATABASE=> \dt
                      List of relations
 Schema |            Name            | Type  |     Owner
--------+----------------------------+-------+----------------
 public | auth_group                 | table | ffnyjettujyfck
 public | auth_group_permissions     | table | ffnyjettujyfck
 public | auth_permission            | table | ffnyjettujyfck
 public | auth_user                  | table | ffnyjettujyfck
 public | auth_user_groups           | table | ffnyjettujyfck
 public | auth_user_user_permissions | table | ffnyjettujyfck
 public | django_admin_log           | table | ffnyjettujyfck
 public | django_content_type        | table | ffnyjettujyfck
 public | django_migrations          | table | ffnyjettujyfck
 public | django_session             | table | ffnyjettujyfck
 public | editor_contentmodel        | table | ffnyjettujyfck
(11 rows)


gollahalli-me-django-test::DATABASE=> \d+ editor_contentmodel
                            Table "public.editor_contentmodel"
  Column   |           Type           | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 ref_id    | character varying(120)   | not null  | extended |              |
 content   | text                     | not null  | extended |              |
 timestamp | timestamp with time zone | not null  | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "editor_contentmodel_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (ref_id)
    "editor_contentmodel_content_2192f49c_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (content, ref_id)
    "editor_contentmodel_ref_id_8f74b4f3_like" btree (ref_id varchar_pattern_ops)
```

It looks like I have to change `"editor_contentmodel_content_2192f49c_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (content, ref_id)` to take `md5(content)`

Can anyone help me with this? I have no clue on how to do it.

**Update:**

`JSON` content - https://gist.github.com/akshaybabloo/0b3dc1fb4d964b10d09ccd6884fe3a40

**Update 2:**

I have created the following `UNIQUE` index, what should I remove in this?

```
gollahalli_me_django=> create unique index on editor_contentmodel (ref_id, md5(content::text));
CREATE INDEX
gollahalli_me_django=> \d editor_contentmodel;
        Table "public.editor_contentmodel"
  Column   |           Type           | Modifiers
-----------+--------------------------+-----------
 ref_id    | character varying(120)   | not null
 content   | jsonb                    | not null
 timestamp | timestamp with time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "editor_contentmodel_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (ref_id)
    "editor_contentmodel_content_2192f49c_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (content, ref_id) <---- 1
    "editor_contentmodel_ref_id_md5_idx" UNIQUE, btree (ref_id, md5(content::text))
    "editor_contentmodel_ref_id_8f74b4f3_like" btree (ref_id varchar_pattern_ops) <----2
```

Should I remove `1` or `2` (See the arrows)?

Comment: You try to index TEXT column, and PostgreSQL (as all other) have limits, for index it 2713, so yes - You can try to change it for MD5 hash for make it smaller

Comment: @a_vlad How should I do that? No idea on how to do it.

Comment: What is content? Is that TEXT or JSON?

Comment: Also, do you ever have two contents, for the same ref_id? If so, what is the purpose of that?

Comment: agree with @EvanCarroll - may be You do not need this index at all?

Comment: @EvanCarroll in content I have JSON. I have only one content for one ref_id. I am calling the contents by ref_id (primary key).

Comment: @a_vlad I am sorry, I am not a DB admin, I have no idea what an index is.

Comment: You should make content then of type `jsonb`,  and you should show what that actually looks like by pasting the content here on a pastebin, gist.github.com

Comment: either way, my answer should provide what you need though.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Added the JSON content

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: @akshay - sorry for delay EvanCarroll give answer, think it enough

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have an UNIQUE index on `(content, ref_id)`, called `editor_contentmodel_content_2192f49c_uniq`

```
"editor_contentmodel_content_2192f49c_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (content, ref_id)
```

I'm not sure why this there to begin with. So let's step back and address what this does. This makes sure that `content`, and `ref_id` are unique. However, in PostgreSQL the `UNIQUE` constraint is implemented with a btree which makes this a poor solution. Using this method, you're creating a btree with content which essentially duplicates the size of this small table, and makes for a gigantic index. A gigantic index that is still limited by content size though -- as you've found. It raises a few questions

- Do you care that content is unique? If you do care that content is unique for ref_id, then what you probably want is to store the *hash* of the content. Something like..

  ```
  CREATE TABLE foo ( ref_id int, content text );
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON foo (ref_id,md5(content));
  ```

  This will instead store the md5sum of content on the btree. So long as ref_id has content with a unique md5 over that ref_id, you're good.
- If you don't care that `content` is unique consider removing it entirely.

It may be worth nothing that when you implement a `UNIQUE` constraint with a btree (as PostgreSQL does), you get an added index for free. Under a normal circumstance this has a fringe benefit.

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( ref_id int, content text );
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON foo (ref_id,content);
```

Will speed up the query

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE ref_id = 5
  AND content = 'This content'
```

However, when you chance it to use the functional `md5()` variant there is no longer an index on content, so now to use that index you'll have to

1. Only query on ref_id,
2. Add to ref_id a clause that `md5(content) = md5('This content')`

The whole `text = text` is over rated. That's almost never what you want. If you're looking to speed up query-time over text the btree is pretty useless. You likely want to look into

1. [pgtrgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html)
2. [text_pattern_ops](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-opclass.html)
3. [Full text search (FTS)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html)

### UPDATE 1

Base on your [JSON](https://gist.github.com/akshaybabloo/0b3dc1fb4d964b10d09ccd6884fe3a40) I would suggest storing it as a `jsonb`, and then creating the index on `md5(content)`; so perhaps rather than the above instead run this.

```
ALTER TABLE public.editor_contentmodel
  ALTER COLUMN content
  SET DATA TYPE jsonb
  USING content::jsonb;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON foo (ref_id,md5(content::text));
```

### UPDATE 2

You ask which indexes you should remove

```
gollahalli_me_django=> create unique index on editor_contentmodel (ref_id, md5(content::text));
CREATE INDEX
gollahalli_me_django=> \d editor_contentmodel;
        Table "public.editor_contentmodel"
  Column   |           Type           | Modifiers
-----------+--------------------------+-----------
 ref_id    | character varying(120)   | not null
 content   | jsonb                    | not null
 timestamp | timestamp with time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "editor_contentmodel_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (ref_id)
    "editor_contentmodel_content_2192f49c_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (content, ref_id) <---- 1
    "editor_contentmodel_ref_id_md5_idx" UNIQUE, btree (ref_id, md5(content::text))
    "editor_contentmodel_ref_id_8f74b4f3_like" btree (ref_id varchar_pattern_ops) <----2
```

Here is the surprising answer: you should remove all of them **except**: `editor_contentmodel_pkey` which says that all `ref_id`'s need to be unique.

1. `editor_contentmodel_content_2192f49c_uniq` this index makes sure that you're `UNIQUE` on `ref_id` AND `content`, but if you can't have a duplicate `ref_id` you can never have a duplicate content for that `ref_id`. So you can *never* violate this index without also violating `editor_contentmodel_pkey`. That makes it pointless.
2. `editor_contentmodel_ref_id_md5_idx` this index is also pointless for the same reason. You can never have a duplicate `md5(content::text)` over `ref_id` because regardless of what the value of `md5(content::text)` is you can never have a duplicate `ref_id`.
3. `editor_contentmodel_ref_id_8f74b4f3_like` is also a bad idea because you're duplicating the index over `ref_id`. This isn't useless, it's just not-optimal. Instead, if you need a `varchar_pattern_ops` use it instead over just the `content` field.

As a last note, we don't much use `varchar` in PostgreSQL because it's implemented as a varlena with a check constraint. There is no gain to it, and there is nothing lost when you simply use `text`. So unless there is a concrete reason why `ref_id` can ever be 120 characters but it can be 119 characters, then I would simply use the `text` type.

### UPDATE 3

Let's go back to your earlier problem..

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: index row size 3496 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "editor_contentmodel_content_2192f49c_uniq"
```

This is telling you the problem is specifically with *index `"editor_contentmodel_content_2192f49c_uniq"`*. You've defined that as

```
"editor_contentmodel_content_2192f49c_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (content, ref_id)
```

So the problem here is that you're trying to create an index over `content`. But, again, the index itself stores the actual json content of `content`, and that's what exceeds the limit. This isn't actually an issue, because even if that limit wasn't in place `editor_contentmodel_content_2192f49c_uniq` would be *totally* useless. Why? again you can't add more uniqueness to a row that is already guaranteed to be 100% unique. You don't seem to be getting this. Let's keep it simple.

```
ref_id | content
1      | 1
1      | 1
1      | 2
2      | 1
```

In the above a lone unique index/constraint (with no other indexes) over `(ref_id, content)` makes sense because it would stop the duplication of `(1,1)`. An index over  `(ref_id, md5(content))` would also make sense because it would stop the duplication of `(1,1)` by proxy of stopping the duplication of `(1, md5(1))`. However all of this works because in the example I've given `ref_id` is *NOT* guaranteed to be `UNIQUE`. Your `ref_id` is not this `ref_id`. Your `ref_id` is a `PRIMARY KEY`. That means it is guaranteed to be UNIQUE.

That means the duplicate `(1,1)` and the row of `(1,2)` could NEVER be inserted. That also means that indexes over anything in addition to ref_id can not guarantee more uniqueness. They would have to be *less* strict than the index you currently have. So your table could only look like this

```
ref_id | content
1      | 1
2      | 1
```

Comment: Can't I alter `editor_contentmodel` tables `column` and add md5 uniqueness to it? or can't we just alter `CONSTRAINT editor_contentmodel_content_2192f49c_uniq UNIQUE (content, ref_id)`? Why is that I have to create a new table for it?

Comment: You don't have to create a new table, I was just showing you how it would look with a simplified version of the table you've got. Just ignore the `CREATE TABLE` command and issue the `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` right below it. Then `DROP` your old index.

Comment: Last question, could you see my `Update 2`

Comment: @akshay updated.

Comment: but if I remove `editor_contentmodel_ref_id_md5_idx` I won't be able to put large contents isn't it? or am wrong?

Comment: @akshay updated again.

Comment: Thank you so much, Evan this helped me a lot. The concept is still a bit shaky (not my field at all). I'll try to learn it.

Comment: I knew you were trying, that's why I kept at it. Glad you're getting your feet wet.

Answer (score 2):

> "editor_contentmodel_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (ref_id)
>      "editor_contentmodel_content_2192f49c_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (content, ref_id)

Since ref_id is the primary key, you can't have duplicate values of it.  That means the unique constraint on the combination (content, ref_id) is useless, as anything that violates that it would also violate the primary key constraint.  Just get rid of it.

Comment: You mean get rid of that and put something like `create unique index on editor_contentmodel (ref_id, md5(content::text))`? or I could recreate the table and remove the primary key.

Comment: I don't know what you want.  If you want the primary key on ref_id, then keep it.  But if you do keep it, then editor_contentmodel_content_2192f49c_uniq is useless, and dropping it will solve your title problem.  Also, if you keep the primary key, then the new index you propose is also useless (useless as a constraint, it might be useful as an index, but that is very unlikely).